# Can't access admin after refreshing cache

Tags: magento-1.9, module, cache, helper

Was trying to create an admin module and got the helper_class not found error

**Fatal error: Class 'my_module_Helper_Data' not found in /home/myweb/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 547**

But now I can't access admin panel after deleting the files I uploaded including the app/etc/modules/my_module.xml.

Tried emptying var/cache but still no luck :/!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weirdest bug I've encountered and just to be clear it was a cache issue and this is how I resolved it:

```
class my_module_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{


}
```

added this code to the bottom of core Mage.php, logged into admin and refreshed cache then removed it back off the bottom of the core Mage.php.

Comment: What isthe general file path to get to the Mage.php file?

Comment: I accessed it trough admin panel it was invisible to my text editor! THANK YOU FOR THIS it saved my ass

Comment: glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Your helper is definitely referenced somewhere.

If disabling the module by setting active to false in the **app/etc/modules/my_module.xml** file does not work, that means the helper is referenced in a file which is not related to the module (template for instance).

Comment: No it's not I had a folder all to itself so I removed all the files it added so I could revert with no worries.

Comment: (locally that is)

Comment: Do you have compilation enabled ? 
Could you post your module config.xml file ?

Comment: Don't have compilation enabled, the module 100% is not referenced anywhere else, it was when I refreshed the cache it happened

Comment: and since the module's config isn't even on the server anymore what difference would it make?

Comment: Did you try removing var/cache files manually by deleting them ? Are you 100% sure you're testing the right website and not a staging/dev version of it ? You can double check that by uploading a simple test.html file to your website and try accessing it in your browser.

Comment: 100% sure I'm going to try cleaning car/cache via ssh because the ftp one is showing its empty

Comment: see my answer it was a server issue I think

Answer (score 0):

Open file `[MAGENTO_ROOT]/includes/config.php`

```
define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');
```

Change these to following

```
#define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
#define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: they are already commented

Comment: Check it by disabling local modules from `app/etc/local.xml`.

Comment: did that and still same thing

Comment: its definitely a caching issue just don't understand why it's not clearing cache, double checked ftp details etc about 20 times lol

Comment: Check  manually deleting `var/cache` directory

Comment: see my answer I'm guessing its an issue with our server